# Do Combat Drugs need to be researched?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Heart of the Swarm, does the Combat Drugs ability of Reapers need to be researched, or does it come automatically? If the former, where is it researched from?

Comment: All infantry research is on the tech lab, so that's where it'd be, if it needed research.

Comment: Heart of the Swarm is not widely available, in it's current form.  That makes it not a good fit for Arqade.

Comment: @fbueckert I concur. I'm voting to close this as "Too Localized", since the game is currently in a **closed** beta. When the game enters an open beta the question could be re-opened.

Comment: If the information is known, it really doesn't matter what form the game is in.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/zead1/summary_of_hots_changes/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://sclegacy.com/news/23-sc2/1157-heart-of-the-swarm-unit-stats), the Combat Drugs ability must be researched at a Tech Lab.

Comment: This source is old.